# How to stack HTML elements on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the background an image. All my other HTML elements will go on top of it. The problem is that it won't stack. Every time I try, the text just goes to the bottom. Also, I want to use vanilla HTML and CSS and do not want to use `canvas`. This is my code.

```css
.navBar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gainsboro;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  z-index: 2;
}

#Title {
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.navBar:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h3 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
  <div>
    <h1 id="Title">A Random Website</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="..." width="100%" height="100%">
<h3>Blablabla</h3>
<br>
<h3>01234567890</h3>
```

Comment: If you want a background-image, then use `background-image` from CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a reason as to why the image has to be in the html, but why not use it in the css directly?

`background: gainsboro url(...) left / cover no-repeat;`

Answer (score 2):

By doing some code change this will works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://rajeshdoot.com/niwax-demos/html/images/about/about-dg-agency.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Blablabla</h3>
    <br>
    <h3>01234567890</h3>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.main .title {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the previous contributor suggested, use the css background-image property instead of embedding an image.

See this jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6zo9h08m/

I used your example code, removed the img element and added a css selector for the body that sets a background-image instead.

```
.navBar{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid gainsboro;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    
 }
 #Title{
    color: black;
    font-family: monospace;
 }
 .navBar:hover{
    border: 2px solid black;
 }
 h3{
    z-index: 2;
 }
 body{
   background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change background image position to 'fixed' and z-index can be less than navbar.

```
style ="position:fixed; z-index:1; top:0px; left:0px;"
```

Instead of inline, you can also give css cass to image tag and css above.

```css
.navBar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gainsboro;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  z-index: 2;
}

#Title {
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.navBar:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h3 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
  <div>
    <h1 id="Title">A Random Website</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="..." style ="position:fixed; z-index:1; top:0px; left:0px;" width="100%" height="100%">
<h3>Blablabla</h3>
<br>
<h3>01234567890</h3>
```